# Netbeans, java importing image (res folder)

Tags: java, image, netbeans, resources

i am prety new in Java and i switch IDE from eclipse to netbeans.... I have problems with importing image in netbeans.
Here is the screen with code and hierarchy, thanks for help (before "xxx" i try lot of wariation, nothing worked):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just copy the image files  from your computer and paste into res folder in neatbeans directly

Comment: Hmm not helped to me.. Can you say me how to correct "make res folder" and what write into "xxx" (screen).
edit: Before i was using Eclipse.. there i make "res" folder, right click and something like "use like resources file" and with "res/textures/test.png" everithing worked.. Now i make same folder res and inside folder textures and not working..

Answer (score 1):

Again hi all.. i solved my problem by this solution:

[image]

- add relative folder to "Libraries" and all is working now.